# Calculate $\int \limits_{A}^{ }\frac{y}{x^3}\, dy\, dx$ with $A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|1\leq xy\leq 2,\, 1\leq \frac xy\leq 2\}$, coordinate-transfo.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, inverse, diffeomorphism, inverse-function-theorem

Calculate $\int \limits_{A}^{ }\frac{y}{x^3}\, dy\, dx$ with $A=\{(x,y)\in (\mathbb{R^+})^2|1\leq xy\leq 2,\, 1\leq \frac xy\leq 2\}$.

Define new coordinates $u=xy\,v=\frac yx$.

Now define $B:=[1,2]^2$ and $h: A\to B, (x,y)\mapsto (u,v)=(xy,\frac yx)$

It is known that $h$ is bijective and continuously differentiable on $B$.

Now The following theorem $(*)$ gets used:

"Let $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open, $f:U\to \mathbb{R}^n$ continuously differentiable (a $C^1$-function) and $a \in U$. If $J_f(a)$ is invertable then $f$ is a local $C^1$-diffeomorphism. "

Now $J_h((x,y))=\begin{pmatrix} y & x \\ \frac{-y}{x^2} & \frac{1}{x} \end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow  \det \begin{pmatrix} y & x \\ \frac{-y}{x^2} & \frac{1}{x} \end{pmatrix}=2\frac{y}{x} >0$ for every $(x,y)\in A$
So $J_h$ is ivertable.

First Question
In the solution to the problem it is stated that $h$ satifys the conditions of $(*)$ and is a $C^1$-diffeomorphism but $A$ is not an open set. Why is $(*)$ applicable?

Next step:

Define $g=h^{-1}$. Now one can apply the transformation formula:

$\int \limits_{g(B)}^{}f(x,y)d(x,y)=\int \limits_{B}^{ }f(g(u,v))\cdot|\det J_g(u,v)|d(u,v)$

Now the second question:

It is stated that the following is true:

$f(g(u,v))\cdot|\det J_g(u,v)|= f(x,y)\cdot \frac{1}{|\det J_h(u,v)|}$

Do you have an idea, what the justification could be?

### Important Edit

I made a mistake. I wrote
$A=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2|1\leq xy\leq 2,\, 1\leq \frac xy\leq 2\}$
instead of $A=\{(x,y)\in (\mathbb{R^+})^2|1\leq xy\leq 2,\, 1\leq \frac xy\leq 2\}$ !

Comment: Re. the second question: [inverse function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function_theorem)

Comment: $h$ is not bijective. $h(-x,-y)=h(x,y).$ $h$ isn't even defined on $B,$ it is defined on $A.$

Comment: You can solve this by defining $A^+=\{(x,y)\in A\mid x,y>0\}$ and get $$\int_A f(x,y)\,dy\,dx=2\int_{A^+} f(x,y)\,dy\,dx$$ when $f(x,y)=f(-x,-y).$ Then $h$ is a bijection on $A^+.$

Comment: "For every $(x,y)\in B.$ " In this theorem, $U=A,$ not $B.$

Comment: I changed $A$ to $A^+$, sry for my mistake, thank you for your observation. I will make the edit to $U=A$ right now

Comment: I still think that there is a problem: $A$ is not an open set, so why is the theorem applicable?

Comment: Define $A’=\{(x,y)\,:\, 1<xy<2, 1<\frac{x}{y}<2\}$. This is an open set, and the integral over $A$ equals the integral over $A’$. Likewise with $B$, define a $B’$. Strict vs weak inequalities aren’t too important for integration (as long as you’re dealing with nice functions) since the difference is a measure zero set (even if you only know about Riemann integration, the concept of ‘measure zero’ should still not be completely foreign).